# Spring AOP with GraalVM Native Image

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspect, graalvm

Is there any way to use aspects in Spring Boot GraalVM native-image? I need it for logging purpose. I got following error on image run:

```
Caused by: org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: AspectJ internal error

        at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld.makeAnnotationFinderIfAny(ReflectionWorld.java:132) ~[na:na]
        at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld.<init>(ReflectionWorld.java:97) ~[na:na]
        at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld.getReflectionWorldFor(ReflectionWorld.java:51) ~[na:na]
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.setClassLoader(PointcutParser.java:222) ~[na:na]
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.<init>(PointcutParser.java:208) ~[na:na]
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.getPointcutParserSupportingSpecifiedPrimitivesAndUsingSpecifiedClassLoaderForResolution(PointcutParser.java:170) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.initializePointcutParser(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:242) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:221) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.obtainPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:198) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:226) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:289) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:321) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:128) ~[com.fon.footballfantasy.FootballFantasyApplication:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:97) ~[com.fon.footballfantasy.FootballFantasyApplication:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:78) ~[com.fon.footballfantasy.FootballFantasyApplication:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:337) ~[com.fon.footballfantasy.FootballFantasyApplication:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:289) ~[com.fon.footballfantasy.FootballFantasyApplication:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:444) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[na:na]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

I suppose that problem is Spring AOP runtime weaving, but how to solve it?

**EDIT:**
Thank you for answers!
Sorry for not providing additional info earlier.
Sample project: https://github.com/programer20/graalvm-demo
I was creating native image by following official documentation *getting started* steps https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/experimental/spring-graalvm-native-docs/0.8.3/spring-graalvm-native-docs-0.8.3.zip!/reference/index.html#_getting_started
I tried with both 0.8.3 and 0.8.5 versions.

Comment: I will try to notify Andy Clement about this post, because he is both the maintainer of AspectJ and one of the brains behind the efforts to make Spring compatible with GraalVM. Meanwhile, it would be good if you could provide more than a stack trace out of context without any code or build information. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally a Maven project on GitHub, also mentioning how you run which GraalVM version etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right about the problem. If you were doing build time weaving, it would be totally fine as the modified byte code will be fed into GraalVM `native-image` for analysis and inclusion in the image. If doing loadtime weaving I *believe* it can work but haven't confirmed recently if you use loadtime weaving at the point the native-image is being built (via setting the java options to include the aspectjweaver agent), the classes will be woven as they are loaded and the woven form will be included in the image. It can never really work at image runtime because there is no notion of classes any more, and classes cannot be dynamically defined.

So yes, since Spring AOP can be done quite late on, as configuration is resolved, there may be problems. Take a look at the [spring native](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native) project for the very latest support building your Spring projects into native-images, but we have no samples there for Spring AOP right now as I recall. I'd encourage you to raise issues against that project, including a sample project that show your specific problem can be invaluable. You haven't mentioned how you are creating the native-image right now which may influence my recommendations. I think pushing some analysis/weaving a bit earlier in the process could make it work but haven't been into that space yet.